# Stuck on trying to prove product rule for limits

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Let

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

$$\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M$$

Then I want to prove that

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) g(x) = LM$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then I want to prove that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ we have $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ implying $|f(x)g(x) - LM| < \epsilon$.

I did this:

$$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x)-LM|&=|f(x)g(x)-Lg(x)+Lg(x)-LM|\\
&=|g(x)(f(x)-L)+L(g(x)-M)|\\
&\le|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M| < \epsilon\end{align}$$

There exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < |x-a| < \delta_1$ implies $|g(x) - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|L|}$. Then:

$$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x)-LM|&\le|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|\\
&<|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L|\frac{\epsilon}{2|L|}   \\
&=|g(x)||f(x)-L|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}  = \epsilon \\
\end{align}$$

I figure for symmetry's sake I should be trying to do the same thing for the other side.

There exists a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < |x-a| < \delta_2$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|M|}$. Then:

$$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x)-LM| &\lt |g(x)||f(x)-L|+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&< |g(x)|\frac{\epsilon}{2|M|}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}   = \epsilon \\
\end{align}$$

Now if I can prove that $|g(x)| \leq |M|$ I could cancel that stuff out and the inequality would hold.

$$|g(x)| = |g(x) - M + M| \leq |g(x) - M| + |M| \leq |M| $$
But then this implies $|g(x) - M| \leq 0 $, but I can't prove it equals zero since this would require $\epsilon = 0$ which is a contradiction.

1. Where did I screw up?
2. Do I need to explicitly state that $L$ and $M$ exist at the beginning? Do I have to take into account situations where they are infinity? Or zero (in case I ever need to divide by $M$ or $L$ anywhere)?
3. The lines where I declared $\delta_1, \delta_2$ to get those absolute-value statements less than some convenient manipulation of $\epsilon$, why am I allowed to do that? It seems weird to me that I can just declare that there exists a $\delta_1$ that makes $|g(x) - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|L|}$. Like, do I have to prove that too? How do I know that's even valid? What stops me from similarly declaring that the $\delta > 0$ exists at the beginning to make $|f(x)g(x) - LM| < \epsilon$ true?

Comment: You certainly don't always have that $|g(x)|\leq |M|$, $g$ could approach $M$ from above. You should state that $L$ and $M$ exist at the beginning since you're assuming they're the limits of your functions. Furthermore, it will help to assume they are finite, as the other cases are more pathological (you could end up with $\infty\cdot 0$ or something equally ugly). For 3. you can always make $|g(x)-M|$ as small as you want because you're assuming that's the limit, the addition of $\frac{1}{2|L|}$ is no issue, just rename $\tilde\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2|L|}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by your definitions we have that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta_1, \delta_2 >0$ such that
$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon, \forall x\in \mathcal{D}(f) \ \text{with}\ 0<|x-a|<\delta_1,$$
and 
$$|g(x) - M| < \epsilon, \forall x\in \mathcal{D}(g) \ \text{with}\ 0<|x-a|<\delta_2,$$
What you continued to do is also sufficient, so following your results we have that

$$|f(x)g(x) - LM| < |g(x)||f(x)-L| + |L||g(x) - M| < |g(x)|\epsilon + |L|\epsilon$$

All that remains to do is bound this $|g(x)|$ part. Take $\epsilon =1$ in the definition of the limit for $g$, then
$$|g(x) - L| <1 \implies |g(x)| < |L| +1,$$
which holds if we choose $\delta_3 = \delta_2(1)$. Thus:
$$|f(x)g(x) - LM| < (|L|+1)|f(x)-L| + |L||g(x) - M| < (|L|+1)\epsilon + |L|\epsilon$$
holds if we take $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3\}$. To make this look more pleasing, you could alter the bounds in the definition of limits for $f$ and $g$ by introducing $L$.

Comment: What is $\forall x\in \mathcal{D}(f)$? For all $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Comment: Wait what lets me say $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x)-M| < \epsilon$?

Comment: This is just my notation for "for all $x$ in the domain of $f$" - sorry for not being clearer with that! If you're working with multiple functions in limit/continuity problems like this, stating the domain in your proofs helps to make it clearer which sets $x$ can belong to (for example in terms of compositions, $x$ can only take values in the intersection of the two domains). :)

Comment: To your second query, this comes from the definition of the limits of $f$ and $g$. We know they both converge to their limits and so the difference can be bounded by $\epsilon$ and if we take $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ we can satisfy **both** inequalities **at the same time**. Hope this helps!

Comment: So it boils down to knowing that the limits exist and that's what lets me plop any old delta or epsilon I want to make them satisfy whatever inequalities I want? I guess that makes sense actually since the very definition of a limit says that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a delta, so that's literally what lets me invoke those deltas if we know the limit exists!

Comment: Yes! Remember that the information we definitely have is that $f$ and $g$ both converge to their limits, and the definition of the limit says that **for all** $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ etc... So we can take $\epsilon$ to be anything (as long as it's positive) we want. Since we know it holds for any possible positive $\epsilon$, there must also be a corresponding $\delta$ (positive) to go with it. It's always good to note down and understand exactly what you **know**, as you have done, before going at a problem

Comment: Makes sense. Should I also be mentioning that $L$ and $M$ not only exist, but that they are finite? I imagine product rule doesn't work when either of them tend to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Remember that if a function "tends to infinity", we don't really say that it's limit **is** $\infty$, we just say the limit doesn't exist, or that it is unbounded (of course we do generally write $\lim f(x) = \infty$). The definition of an infinite limit looks slightly different to the finite version you have written in the question.

Comment: So was my error using things like $|L|$ and $|M|$ rather than $|L|+1$ and $|M|+1$? I can't tell if I made an error or just chose the wrong epsilon forms.

Comment: On the last line of calculation you have added and taken away an $M$ and applied the triangle inequality. You try to bound it by $|M|$, but the $|g(x) - M|$ part just vanished, however you could have replaced it by an $\epsilon$ and had the bound as $\epsilon + |M|$ which is the same thing as I have done above, but I chose a specific epsilon and carrier it out, whereas you have done it **for all** $\epsilon$ which is still valid, however the end result (i.e. the bound you get for the product part) will have an $\epsilon^2$ in it, which is still okay mathematically, but looks a little messy!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to control like $|g(x)-M|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(|L|+1)}$ and then $|L||g(x)-M|\leq\dfrac{|L|\epsilon}{2(|L|+1)}<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ because $L$ could be zero.

Now control one $\delta'>0$ such that $|g(x)-M|<1$ (or any other constant) then $|g(x)|\leq|g(x)-M|+|M|<1+|M|$, so by taking minimum $\delta=\min\{\delta',\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ we have $|g(x)||f(x)-L|<(1+|M|)|f(x)-L|<\dfrac{(1+|M|)\epsilon}{2}$ for all $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: Interesting, so is that where I screwed up? Using denominators of the form $|M|$ rather than $|M|+1$?

Comment: Not really, that is just a minor issue. Rather, you need to control the behavior of $g$ such that $|g(x)|$ is bounded whenever $x$ is closed to $a$, then you are allowed to control the whole $|g(x)||f(x)-L|$ to be some sort of $C|f(x)-L|$ for some constant $C>0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$|f(x)g(x)-LM|\le|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|$$

you have taken care of $$|L||g(x)-M|< \epsilon/2$$

For

$$|g(x)||f(x)-L|$$Make $$|g(x)|<M+1$$ and $$ |f(x)-L|< \frac {\epsilon}{2(M+1)}$$

by choosing your $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ small enough.