# Need an intuitive understanding of Product Rule of limits

Tags: limits, inequality, proof-explanation

Why should we take  =1 as mentioned in the answer? What is so special about 1?

I understand the proof but not the intuition behind that.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2673874/474539

Comment: Nothing special. We just need to pick some positive value (try the same proof with 20.23 instead of 1 - there will be minor changes but it will still go through). Since the value doesn't matter, people often pick 1, as that feels like a pretty "generic, non-special" number. The key point is that it is bounded - what the specific bound is doesn't matter that much.

Comment: There's nothing special about choosing $\varepsilon$ to be $1$. For the argument in that answer to work, the $|g(x)|$ term needs to be bounded near $a$, and choosing a particular $\varepsilon$ yields an upper bound. Any choice of $\varepsilon$ works to this end because if $|g(x)-L|<\varepsilon$, it follows that $L-1<g(x)<L+1$, which implies $|g(x)|$ is bounded.